# How to check if a given process is running when having its handle

Tags: windows, delphi, process, handle

I am using `ShellExecuteEx` to start an application.
After successful start im reading `TShellExecuteInfo.hProcess` to obtain a handle of the started process.

I would like to periodically check if the process started by my application is still running.
Two or more processess with the same name can run simultaneously and I want to be sure that my application is checking the correct process.

I want to be able to do this on Windows systems from Windows 2000 to above.

I know that there is WinAPI function `GetProcessId` which is doing exactly what I want but it does not support Windows 2000.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Since you have the handle to the process, I don't know what you mean by "I want to be sure that my application is checking the correct process". How could it not be the correct process since you have the handle already?

Comment: @David I felt that I need to emphasise my requirement just in case that somone could suggest me solution like this: http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/check_if_a_process_is_running.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx) on that handle, and use a timeout parameter of zero. If the process is still running, the function will return `Wait_Timeout`; if the process has terminated, then it will return `Wait_Object_0` (because process termination causes its handles to become *signaled*.)

If you want to know what the exit status of the process is, then call [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189.aspx).

Comment: You can just call `GetExitCodeProcess` test the return value again `STILL_ACTIVE`.

Comment: Unless the exit code *is* `Still_Active`, @David. Then you still need some other way to differentiate, and if you don't actually *care* what the exit code is, may as well just call `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: Would be nice to spell Wait_Timeout in uppercase for easier cut'n'paste (+1 all the same ;-) )

Comment: I accidentally clicked the wrong button on the review queue. @Kupiakos, please don't keep changing Rob's code to uppercase - he rolled back your change once, and we don't need an edit war.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I figured it was rolled back because too much was changed, and not just capitalization. I changed only the capitalization this time, as that's the only part that's factually incorrect (as described in [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx)).

Comment: @Kupiakos, fair enough, that makes sense. Just, if that edit gets either rejected or rolled back again, please just leave it be all the same, to prevent an edit war. Thanks!

Comment: I rejected your edits, @Kupiakos, because there were no capitalization errors to "fix." As you know, Delphi is not case sensitive, so we can use mixed case to keep words more readable instead of using the original case inflicted on us. (If you didn't know that, then you shouldn't be editing answers to Delphi questions.) I also didn't appreciate you removing the semicolon. (And you didn't even fix the *actual* typo.)

Comment: @RobKennedy I intended to make an improvement. The second time, I realized I went a little far and fixed only what was necessary. I didn't even fix the typo the second time through. This problem is not Delphi-exclusive. The only possible indication of Delphi being used is the tag. It would actually much better fit in the tag `winapi` than `delphi`, as the problem is about how to use the Windows API. I found this problem on Google trying to solve the same problem in C. I'd rather not start an editor war, but reverting an edit that causes the answer to be *more* applicable is ridiculous.