# Why does OpenProcess() return a non 0 value when the process ID is no longer running

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm starting a new instance of another application using `CreateProcess` from [Example](https://riptutorial.com/delphi/example/18340/createprocess) and I end up saving the PID so that I can later check if that process is still running.

I'm using to following method to check if it's running or not:

```
procedure TfrmRSM.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var
  ahandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, true, aPID);

  if ahandle = 0 then
    ShowMessage('is not running')
  else
    ShowMessage('is running');

  CloseHandle(ahandle);
end;
```

The code above should return `0` when the process is no longer running but it still returns a number greater than `0`

I am closing the handle after using CreateProcess

Whats to propper way to check if a PID is running if the method I'm using is incorrect? I'm only able to find methods that use the application name.

Comment: Did you close all handles to the process after you called `CreateProcess`?

Comment: You should keep `hProcess` and use it to check if the process has terminated (for instance with [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess)).

Comment: I'm not sure what your edit adds, other than showing that you call `CloseHandle` passing an invalid handle value in case `aHandle` is zero. Your edit certainly doesn't answer the question I asked, if you read it closely. If you want to check whether the process has terminated, then you should ask about that, because the code in the question is the wrong way to do that. And what's the point in addressing the code and approach here when it's the wrong approach. We still don't know what you did with the handles returned by `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @Olivier I can't keep it because my application is not always running.

Comment: Well you can't keep a PID either because they are recycled. Windows can reuse a PID whenever it wants.

Comment: I understand. What would be the best approach for this then or should I ask another question on here?

Comment: Are you the author of the spawned process? If you are, you could write something into a file just before it exits to notify it's done.

Comment: I'm not the author no.

Comment: Then I'm afraid all is left is what you said: *"I'm only able to find methods that use the application name"*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234120/discussion-between-adriaan-boshoff-and-olivier).

Comment: If you want a good answer, ask a good question :-) It looks like you want to know if one or more instances of an application is still running. It is your application which starts the instances but your application may quit before the instance and restarted and you still want after the restart check if the instances are running. Did I correctly summarized your need?

Comment: @fpiette I want to check if a process I created is still running later even after I quit my application and opened it again. The main question did not change and it's still about why the handler isn't 0 when the process is no longer running even if there's no process with the same recycled ID.

Comment: @AdriaanBoshoff When you create the process you receive a handle to that process from `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx`, whichever you used - that's what you need to be saving, not the PID.  Then you simply use that handle to [determine whether it is still running.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6493626/327083)

Comment: @J... It doesn't work here because the main process can be restarted, which means you lose the handle of the spawned process.

Comment: @Olivier Well, if that's a constraint and OP doesn't like enumerating by name for PIDs, then the only solution I can think of is to write a system service that manages these external processes.  It can manage the handles, starting, and stopping of those processes across restarts of the main user-session process.  OP can use IPC to communicate with their service to instruct it to open, close, or list the outstanding processes it has created, etc.

Comment: Did you close all handles to the process after you called `CreateProcess`? It's kind of a simple question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm starting a new instance of another application using CreateProcess from Example and I end up saving the PID so that I can later check if that process is still running.

The correct way to handle this is to keep open the `HANDLE` that `CreateProcess()` gives you, and then you can query it via `WaitForSingleObject()` or `GetExitCodeProcess()` to see if the process has terminated or not, and then close the `HANDLE` when you no longer need it.

In comments, you mention that your launching app may terminate and be restarted separate from the target process.  In that case, you could close the `HANDLE` if you still have it open, saving its PID and creation date/time somewhere you can get it back from, and then when your app restarts it can [enumerate running processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) ([alternatively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)) to see if the target EXE is still running and has a matching PID and date/time, and if so then open a new `HANDLE` to that PID.  Just be careful, because this does introduce a small race condition where the target process might terminate after you detect its presence and its PID could get recycled before you have a chance to open it.  So you might need to re-validate the `HANDLE`'s info again after opening it.

Otherwise, during your app's shutdown (or even before), you can off-load the open `HANDLE` from `CreateProcess()` to a separate helper process that stays running in the background monitoring the `HANDLE`, and then your main app can get the `HANDLE` back from that helper after restarting.  Or, perform the actual `CreateProcess()` call in the helper to begin with, so the `HANDLE` monitoring stays within a single process at all times, and let your main app query the helper for status when needed.

> I'm using to following method to check if it's running or not:

That will not work, as you don't know whether the PID is still valid, or even still refers to the same process you are interested in. Once that process has terminated, its PID can be recycled at any time for use with a new process.

> The code above should return 0 when the process is no longer running but it still returns a number greater than 0

The only way `OpenProcess()` can return non-zero is if the specified PID is actually running.  But that does not guarantee it is the same process you are interested in.  At the very least, after `OpenProcess()` returns a non-zero `HANDLE`, you can query that `HANDLE` for its info (EXE file path, creation date/time, etc) to see if it is the same process you are expecting.  If the info does not match, the PID was recycled.

Comment: A way to improve reliability would be to log the StartDate/Time of the process along the PID.  And when trying to match the PID to a running process, check if GetProcessTimes return values coherent with the  StartDate/Time originally logged.

Comment: @KenBourassa thanks, I have added that to my answer.

Comment: @KenBourassa I already had that in my answer - was it ignored or read and copied into your comment?

Answer (score 1):

To wait for a process to end, simply use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) on the process handle: when the process ends, the handle is signaled and the function returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`. This ensures that you "look" at the handle the whole time it lives, instead of only inspecting it from time to time and otherwise leave it unattended.

Most likely you put this into a separate thread, and upon its ending you have your event to react to when the watched process ended. If you have multiple handles to look for, use [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) - be aware that it can't handle more than 64 (`MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`) handles at once.

---

**Edit:** when not being able to track a process handle entirely you can at least use [`GetProcessTimes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes) to check if the process you're looking at still started at the same time you looked at it last time - that should make it pretty distinctive: when the process handle is recycled by a new process then at least its starting time should differ.

Comment: I can just save the handle to a file right in case my application restarts and I need to check later?

Comment: The OP said that the main process can be restarted, so you can't keep the handle of the spawned process.

Comment: @Olivier Cant I just save the handle to a text file since it's a integer?

Comment: @AdriaanBoshoff No you can't. A handle is actually a pointer, contrary to the PID (which is really an integer).

Comment: PID and handles are recycled. You can't just save it a later restore and check it.

Comment: Could a process ID get recycled while the process is running?

Comment: @AdriaanBoshoff no. But if you don't keep an open handle to the process, it could terminate and have its PID recycled at any time before you knew it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does OpenProcess() return a non 0 value when the process ID is no
> longer running?

This is probably an undefined behavior or the PID has been recycled by Windows.

> I want to check if a process I created is still running later even
> after I quit my application and opened it again.

You said you cannot change the process. One work around is to use an intermediate and very simple process to launch the target process. The intermediate process can use any IPC (for example shared memory of shared file) to talk to the main process to inform it about running target process. This intermediate process will run the target process and update a flag that the main process can query (In my example in shared memory).

The intermediate process can also simply keep a file open for exclusive access while the target process is running. The main process can try to open the file and if it succeed, then the target process is done (Intermediate process use `WaitForSingleObject`or `WaitForMultipleObject` to wait for target process termination).